# Eliminating space between number and currency

Tags: php, spacing

My script for showing the discount amount or percentage is;

```
function DisplayDiscount($value)
    {
        if (strstr($value,'%'))
             $discount = "%".substr($value, 0, -1); //$discount = $value;
        else
            $discount = $value.SITE_CURRENCY;

        return $discount;
    }
```

Outcomes;

- %18.30
- 18.30 XX

I want to eliminate the space between the value and XX but I could not figure it out.

Comment: `$discount = trim($value) . SITE_CURRENCY;`

Comment: $discount = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $discount ); should do

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks but did not work for me

Comment: @Satya thanks but did not work for me

Comment: Then check exactly where the space exists.... debugging 101... check the values of $value and SITE_CURRENCY to see where the space is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to like This:

```
    $input = " aa bb ";
    $output = str_replace(" ","",$input);
    echo $output;
```